# Contingency Table between to Vector (polygon) Layers

Tags: qgis, spatial-statistics, zonal-statistics

I have two polygon layers (Soil Type and Glacial Geology).

I want to see the relation of the two as a contingency table.

Recall doing this in ArcGIS. I forget the tool but it gave me a list of from/to counts. I used a pivot table in Excel to get the contingency table.

How do I do this in QGIS?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to define "contingency table"